# laravel a href validation

Tags: php, html, laravel

I would like to ask if it is possible to validate a href element in laravel.

---

For example, I'm having a bunch of people responses in my guest book and each user is able do delete his posts. I'm deleting it like this:

```
 <div class="col-lg-2">
   <ul class="list-unstyled trash">
      <li> 
        <a href="/responses/{{$response->id}}">       
         <span onclick="alertDialog()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></li>
         <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$response->id}}">Edit</button></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Unfortunately, every single user can change `"/responses/{{$response->id}}">` id via browser developer tools and delete other user's responses. Is there any possible solutions to prevent this issue?

Comment: Also you could hash `{{$response->id}}` so no one can change it

Comment: you can just use ctrl+c ctrl+v combination then

Comment: but that is the part when you apply the solution i gave you, you just render the post of the logged in user so if he do ctrl+c and ctrl+v he will be deleting his won posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the logged user before rendering that html section:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
   <!-- assuming post is your variable and user is a property which references the user who created the record -->
   @if($post->user == Auth::id())
   <ul class="list-unstyled trash">
      <li> 
        <a href="/responses/{{$response->id}}">       
         <span onclick="alertDialog()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></li>
         <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$response->id}}">Edit</button></li>
   </ul>
   @endif
 </div>
```

This way only the user who owns the post will be able to see the button in the html.

Comment: I was thinking like this but if I have two posts I still can delete each post using another post's delete button. I don't think that is a good solution. But thanks :)

Comment: So in you delete method just check that the user of the post is the same as the logged in user. That way you will have double verification

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#generating-policies) to check if the user that tries to delete a record is its owner:

```
public function delete(User $user, Model $model)
{
    return $user->id === $model->user_id;
}
```

Or you can do it manually in a controller method:

```
if (auth()->id() === $model->user_id) {
    // Delete the record
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `/responses/{{$response->id}}` a `POST` route and verify that the passed `id` matches with the authenticated users id. ( `Auth::user()->id;`)